# How to add the VLAN information using virt-install to VM xml file?

Tags: xml, virtual-machine, kvm, libvirt, openvswitch

I'm trying to automate virtual machine creation but I'm having troubles adding the VLAN tag to the xml file via virt-install.

```
sudo virt-install --name hosp10 --memory 16384 --vcpus 4 \
  --disk /var/lib/libvirt/images/cloud-full.qcow2,format=qcow2,cache=none,target=vda \
  --boot kernel=/var/lib/libvirt/images/full.vmlinuz,initrd=/var/lib/libvirt/images/full.initrd,kernel_args="root=/dev/vda" \
  --network bridge=br-mgmt,model=virtio,virtualport_type=openvswitch,mac=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

I'm looking to add to --network something like vlan_id=100 but seems such option doesn't exist. Is there a way to have xml generated like the following?

```
<interface type="bridge">
      <source bridge="ovs-internal"/>
      <target dev='ext01'/>
      <vlan>
        <tag id='100'/>
      </vlan>
      <model type="virtio"/>
      <virtualport type="openvswitch"/>
      <mac address='vv:vv:vv:vv:vv:vv' />
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do that directly using `virt-install`, but why don't you configure the VLAN tag using Open vSwitch?

```
# after running virt-install:
ovs-vsctl set port ext01 tag=100
```

Comment: This is what I'm doing at the moment but doing *set* as the port got already created by libvirt, and also alternative is to just manually add it to the xml file. I was hoping for automatically add it through xml and maintain a repo/versions of them there.

Comment: Oh, right! I fixed the `set`. Thanks!
I went through the libvirt documentation and couldn't find a way to do it directly with the command line tools. What's the issue with the OVS or XML solutions?

Comment: It's just extra steps in my automation..etc. Thanks a lot for your answer, I though I check first with the community gurus if there was something i was missing in virt-install in his topic.

Comment: Glad I could provide a second pair of eyes! Not an OVS gurus though :-)

Comment: Libvirt lets you configure OVS VLAN port settings inside of the domain XML. This solution is inadequate because it externalizes the VLAN config into a different tool.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with version 3.0.0, `virt-install` has an `--xml` option that lets you use XPath syntax to directly modify the XML of the domain when creating it.

To add VLAN configuration, you'd add an `--xml` option like this:

```sh
virt-install \
  --network bridge=br-mgmt,model=virtio,virtualport_type=openvswitch,mac=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX \
  --xml './devices/interface/vlan/tag/@id=100' \
  <additional args>
```

This should add `<vlan><tag id="100"/></vlan>` to the first interface device.

If you have multiple interfaces, you can use XPath syntax to select the desired interface.  E.g., `./devices/interface[2]/vlan/tag/@id=100` would modify the second interface.